# How can I add an incomplete row in a Panda DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to copy a row from a DataFrame to another. The issue comes from that the origin has not as many columns as the destination, leading to a situation looking like :

```py
origin = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],
                      [3,4]],columns=['A','B'])
destination = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

copy = origin[0:1].to_dict()
destination.loc[0] = copy
```

I'm getting a 'ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns'
I tested with two identical df, and it worked fine. What would be the best way to do what I'm trying? I was thinking of dynamically add NaNs for the additional destination columns, but it doesn't seem very pythonic.

Please note that I'm trying to avoid any append(), as I will perform the task frequently, and I read in Pandas doc that it would probably give perfomance issues.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `Series`

```
destination.loc[0]=pd.DataFrame(copy).iloc[0]
destination
Out[672]: 
     A    B   C
0  1.0  2.0 NaN
```